# Seeing an error (set.2.value) is required when trying to create EKS addons using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

`Following is the error i am seeing when deploying an eks addon.

`with module.kubernetes_addons["0"].module.aws_load_balancer_controller[0].module.helm_addon.helm_release.addon[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/kubernetes_addons/modules/kubernetes-addons/helm-addon/main.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "addon":

```
1: resource "helm_release" "addon" {
```

│
│ The argument "set.2.value" is required, but no definition was found.

`

Below is the module usage

```
module "kubernetes_addons" {
  for_each = { for idx, _ in var.cluster_ids : idx => idx }
  source   = "<calling addons module here>"

  eks_cluster_id       = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.id
  eks_cluster_endpoint = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.endpoint
  eks_oidc_provider    = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer
  eks_cluster_version  = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.version

  
  data_plane_wait_arn = data.local_file.kube_system_fargate_profile_arn[each.key].content


  enable_amazon_eks_coredns    = true
  enable_amazon_eks_vpc_cni    = true
  enable_amazon_eks_kube_proxy = true
  enable_cluster_config        = true


  enable_aws_load_balancer_controller = true


  aws_load_balancer_controller_helm_config = {
    set_values = [
      {
        name  = "replicaCount"
        value = var.replicas_aws_load_balancer_controller
      }
    ]


  }

  iam_role_path            = local.iam_role_path
  iam_permissions_boundary = local.iam_role_permissions_boundary

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    data.http.eks_cluster_readiness[0],
  ]
}
```

Inside helm_addon folder :

main.tf

```
resource "helm_release" "addon" {
  name             = var.helm_config["name"]
  dynamic "set" {
    iterator = each_item
    for_each = try(var.helm_config["set"], null) != null ? distinct(concat(var.set_values, var.helm_config["set"])) : var.set_values

    content {
      name  = each_item.value.name
      value = each_item.value.value
      type  = try(each_item.value.type, null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "set_sensitive" {
    iterator = each_item
    for_each = try(var.helm_config["set_sensitive"], null) != null ? concat(var.helm_config["set_sensitive"], var.set_sensitive_values) : var.set_sensitive_values

    content {
      name  = each_item.value.name
      value = each_item.value.value
      type  = try(each_item.value.type, null)
    }
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "helm_config" {
  description = "Helm chart config. Repository and version required. See https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs"
  type        = any
}

variable "set_values" {
  description = "Forced set values"
  type        = any
  default     = []
}

variable "set_sensitive_values" {
  description = "Forced set_sensitive values"
  type        = any
  default     = []
}
```

Inside load balancer folder (source = "./aws-load-balancer-controller")

main.tf

```
 module "helm_addon" {
  source            = "../helm-addon"
  gitops            = var.gitops
  set_values        = local.set_values
  helm_config       = local.helm_config
  addon_context     = var.addon_context
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  name            = "aws-load-balancer-controller"

 
  default_helm_config = {
    name        = local.name
    chart       = local.name
    namespace   = "alb-system"
    values      = local.default_helm_values
  }

  helm_config = merge(
    local.default_helm_config,
    var.helm_config
  )



  set_values = concat(
    [
      {
        name  = "serviceAccount.name"
        value = local.service_account
      },
      {
        name  = "serviceAccount.create"
        value = false
      },
      {
        name  = "vpcId"
        value = var.addon_context.vpc_id
      }
    ],
    try(var.helm_config.set_values, [])
  )


  iam_config = {
    kubernetes_namespace                = local.helm_config["namespace"]
    kubernetes_service_account          = local.service_account
    create_kubernetes_namespace         = try(local.helm_config["create_namespace"], true)
    create_kubernetes_service_account   = true
    create_service_account_secret_token = true
  }
}
```

Currently, this is where it is failing, all i am trying to do here is to enable load balancer controller addon and set replica count, not sure what's the issue here,  following attribute is needed aws_load_balancer_controller_helm_config, as soon as i add it, i get an error saying set.2.value is required. And if i try to add the set attribute, still fails saying set.3.value is required..

I am not sure what's missing here and how to handle this error

```
  aws_load_balancer_controller_helm_config = {
    set = [
      {
        name  = "replicaCount"
        value = var.replicas_aws_load_balancer_controller
      }
    ]


  }
```